# Properties of objects on array (Objective-c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, object, properties

I have a `NSObject` class which's name is `test.`
class `test` has 3 property. `Name`, `age`, `id`;
I have 3 Objects in test class. `s`, `b`, `c`.
I am putting all of the objects to the array with: `NSArray *ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];`
I am trying to access to the data of property in that array. Which means I have to read, write the property of the object in array in the loop (for loop or while loop).
I found a lot of materials on the internet. The method that I was close to do was:

```
[[ary objectAtIndex:0] setName:@"example"];
```

This method was working with setters and getters. But it did give a horrible error. Is there any "WORKING" method to do it?
Thanks...

Comment: @userXXX Now the title's better. (We don't appreciate all caps on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: The three objects in your array are the character strings "a", "b", and "c".  NSStrings are immutable so you can't change them.

Comment: "A horrible error" is rather nonspecific.

Comment: Do this:  `NSArray *ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a, b, c, nil];`

Comment: You say you have an array of `test` objects, but you don't. You have an array of strings. If you want an array of objects, you have to create three instances of your `test` class and add those to your array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's imagine a `Person` class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger age;
@property (nonatomic) long long identifier;

+ (instancetype)personWithName:(NSString *)name age:(NSInteger)age identifier:(long long)identifier;

@end

@implementation Person

+ (instancetype)personWithName:(NSString *)name age:(NSInteger)age identifier:(long long)identifier {
    Person *person = [[self alloc] init];
    person.name = name;
    person.age = age;
    person.identifier = identifier;

    return person;
}

@end
```

You can then create an array of people like so:

```
NSArray *people = @[[Person personWithName:@"Rob" age:32 identifier:2452323],
                    [Person personWithName:@"Rachel" age:29 identifier:84583435],
                    [Person personWithName:@"Charlie" age:4 identifier:389433]];
```

You can then extract an array of people's names like so:

```
NSArray *names = [people valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@", names);
```

That will generate:

```
2013-09-27 14:57:13.791 MyApp[33198:a0b] (
    Rob,
    Rachel,
    Charlie
)
```

If you want to extract information about the second `Person`, that would be:

```
Person *person = people[1];
NSString *name = person.name;
NSInteger age = person.age;
long long identifier = person.identifier;
```

If you want to change the age of the third person, it would be:

```
Person *person = people[2];
person.age = 5;
```

Or, if you want to iterate through the array to extract the information, you can do that, too:

```
for (Person *person in people) {
    NSString *name = person.name;
    NSInteger age = person.age;
    long long identifier = person.identifier;

    // now do whatever you want with name, age, and identifier
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

STEP 1 : Cast it to the appropriate object type first

```
s *myS = (s *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
b *myB = (b *)[array objectAtIndex:1]; 
c *myC = (c *)[array objectAtIndex:2];
```

STEP 2 : Set / get whatever property you want to

```
myS.name = @"example";
```

Comment: STEP 2.5: REMOVE ALL CAPS FROM THE WORD "STEP". Step 3: remove the harmful typecasts as well, because `objectAtIndex:` returns `id`. Step 4: use the more verbose subscript notation for `NSArray` instead of `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Step 5: apply cold water to burn.